# Difference between install methods for typings

Tags: npm-install, typescript-typings

I'm learning Typscript in connection with Angular2 and I'm having a hard time to understand typings and how they are installed. I'm stuck at a point where my project will not start correctly and I guess this is because of me not understanding the usage of typings. So, my question is:

What is the actual difference between "npm install typings -g" and "typings install"? Where do the typings go to? How can I uninstall them? What is the difference in scope / accessability?

Answer (score 0):

Typings provide a way to manage and install typescript definition files for 3rd party libraries such as jquery.

npm install typings -g>>
This helps us to install typings globally on the machine. the -g tells npm to install the package globally.
We install typings so that they can enable us to download typescript definition files of other libraries.

**Why do we need Typescript definition files**

Typescript uses types among other things to direct the developper on possible causes of errors. This therefore implies that if we can use the typescript definition files for a library such as jquery then typescript will be able to point out errors for us when we are using jquery.

Think of the typescript definition file as eg jquery written in typescript. These files however end in .d.ts and this tells typescript not to transpile them to javascript.

**Typings install**

This actually installs the typescript definition file.

eg

```
typings install react
```

The above line will install typescript definition files for react.

```
npm install typings
```

The above line will install typings that enable you install typescript definition files for other libraries.

You can read more about typings here..[Typings](https://github.com/typings/typings)

**Where they are stored**

Typings will be stored inside your project root in a folder called typings

**Please Note**

Typescript definition files only help you during development and that you will also need to install the actual 3rd party library

For example for react, you would need both of these

```
npm install react
typings install react
```